# JsonRpcProvider RPC call results wrong while BrowserProvider works well

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, ethereumjs

I'm facing really weird phemomenon..

What Im doing is, Im instantiating Wallet with my private key,

and trying to send ERC-20 methods to endpoint ('https://ethereum.publicnode.com')

```
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider('https://ethereum.publicnode.com')
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet('my private key' , provider)
const method = 'eth_accounts'

const result = await wallet.provider!.send(method ,[]);
console.log(result) // []
```

but if I only change JsonRpcProvider to BrowserProvider, it works well

```
const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum)
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet('my private key' , provider)
const method = 'eth_accounts'

const result = await wallet.provider!.send(method ,[]);
console.log(result) // ['my wallet address']
```

I really can't figure out what is the problem.. really need some help..